# Migrating Postgres server from Windows to Linux

Tags: postgresql, replication, datafile

Simple question: I want to migrate all of a Postgres server's data, schema, roles, everything from Windows to Linux.

Can I just copy the contents of the `%PGDATA%` directory in Windows to which the server points to Linux and start the server there pointing PGDATA argument/variable to that directory? In other words, are the data files platform independent to make porting from one OS to another a matter of copying?

I also have developed a script for cloning PG databases, schema+data but, for a variety of reasons, I would prefer to just put the data files on a USB drive and be done with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot do that. The files in the data directory are not compatible across operating systems (or different architectures).

You will need to use `pg_dump` and `pg_restore`

Comment: You may also need to care about encoding or collation for some languages.

Answer (score -1):

Just for the record, you should ask in PostgreSQL mailing list.

My personal idea is the binary format is fixed, so no problem.

Anyway, just to try, I:

a) copy the pgdata directory, from PG9.5 from Windows Server 2012 to Linux;

b) compile 9.5 on Linux;

c) change the specific Windows options in postgresql.conf;

d) run it...

And it starts, but it complains about locale (I have to investigate further to figure out):

> LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2020-02-27
>   03:57:27 CET
>
> LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery
>   in progress
>
> LOG:  redo starts at 34/DFD49EF8
>
> LOG:  invalid record length at 34/DFE33560
>
> LOG:  redo done at 34/DFE33538
>
> LOG:  last completed transaction was at log time 2020-02-27
>   04:00:52.844739+01
>
> LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
>
> LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
>
> LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
>
> FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[local]", user "gelma",
>   database "postgres"
>
> FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[local]", user "gelma",
>   database "postgres"
>
> FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[local]", user "gelma",
>   database "template1"
>
> FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[local]", user "gelma",
>   database "template0"
>
> FATAL:  role "gelma" does not exist
>
> FATAL:  database locale is incompatible with operating system
>
> DETAIL:  The database was initialized with LC_COLLATE
>   "Italian_Italy.1252",  which is not recognized by setlocale().
>
> HINT:  Recreate the database with another locale or install the
>   missing locale.
>
> FATAL:  database locale is incompatible with operating system
>
> DETAIL:  The database was initialized with LC_COLLATE
>   "Italian_Italy.1252",  which is not recognized by setlocale().

Anyway the server is up and running.
Also using pg_dump I don't think the locale is automagically converted.

So, finding the original super user and how to change collate/locale should be the only things left.